# AS3 How to make a button toggle a function?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, function, cursor, toggle

When button1 is clicked, the cursor changes into a 'movieclip'
I want this movieclip cursor to switch back into a regular cursor
when button1 is clicked again, so toggle the function on and off.

My question to you is, is it likely to use some kind of boolean here to toggle the function on and off or am I in the wrong direction?
Thanks in advance!

```
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,wipe);

function wipe(e:Event):void 
{

        Mouse.hide();
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,follow);
        function follow(evt:MouseEvent)
              {
              cursor.x = mouseX;
              cursor.y = mouseY;
              }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
protected function wipe(e:Event):void {
    if (stage.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, follow) {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, follow);
    } else {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, follow);
    }
}
```

I'd move the definition of follow out of wipe.  Does that even work?

If you need to have other listeners for MOUSE_MOVE directly on the stage then you might want to go with something more like:

```
protected var isFollowing:Boolean;
protected function wipe(e:Event):void {
    if (isFollowing) {
       stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, follow);
   } else {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, follow);
   }
   isFollowing = !isFollowing;
}
```

Note: I've assumed you're going to put your code into a document Class, since I always assume that if you care enough to ask on a place like Stack Overflow, you'd like to use good practice.

Comment: Thank you for your anwer, Amy. Yes the wipe function worked. When I use your code i get this error; 1150: The protected attribute can only be used on class property definitions.

Comment: Amy Blankenship, wtf how YOU could recommend such code? stage might have another MOUSE_MOVE handler defined somewhere else, so this code won't work properly.

Comment: Is your code in a frame script?  That's not really good practice, so I assumed that you were using a document Class.  If you are using a frame script and you're planning to keep it that way, just leave out "protected."

Comment: Pavel--I hadn't thought of it in terms of a multi-developer/large project.  I'm editing the answer now.

Comment: I'd think, though, that it would be pretty rare to need to listen to the entire stage for a mouse move from multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

```
var isMC:Boolean=false;


button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,wipe);
cursor.visible=false;
function wipe(e:Event):void 
{
if(isMC==false){
    cursor.visible=true;
    Mouse.hide();
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,follow);
    function follow(evt:MouseEvent)
          {
          cursor.x = mouseX;
          cursor.y = mouseY;

          }
          isMC=true;}else{Mouse.show();
          cursor.visible=false;
          isMC=false

}}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you explain _why_ this might help?